# Bootstrap Tags auto clear custom values after type

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im using [bootstrap-tagsinput](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput). Below code is working fine but I want to make auto clear the particular input value which not exist from the json. User need to select from tags only he can't submit custom values. I also used "freeInput: false" but still it display the values in frontend. Please help me to fix this.

[image]

Jquery

```
var languages = new Bloodhound({
 datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name')
 , queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
 , prefetch: './assets/languages.json'
});
languages.initialize();
$('#inputtag').tagsinput({
 freeInput: false
 , typeaheadjs: {
     name: 'id'
     , displayKey: 'name'
     , valueKey: 'name'
     , limit: 10
     , source: languages.ttAdapter()
 }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" id="inputtag" value="" name="language[]" required data-msg-required="Please enter your language" multiple class="form-control tag">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code, this may help you.

```
var languages = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name')
 , queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
 , prefetch: './assets/languages.json'
});

languages.initialize();
$('#inputtag').tagsinput({
 freeInput: false
 , addOnBlur : false
 , typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'id'
    , displayKey: 'name'
    , valueKey: 'name'
    , source: languages.ttAdapter()
  }
});

$('#inputtag').tagsinput('input').blur(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Check this issue on [github](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/236)